# Almacenar en una lista datos generados en un ciclo for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema, dentro de un ciclo `for` tengo una variable que va cambiando de valor y quiero guardar cada valor que genere dentro de una lista para usarla en otras operaciones. En mi caso la variable que va cambiando de valor es `Asx`, y quiero almacenar cada valor que genere en una lista.

```
M = [2,5,6,8,7]  
fy = 4200  
h = 30  
b = 20  
d = 0.90*h  


for i in M:  
   Asx = (i*100000)/(0.81*fy*d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cesar, lo más práctico es convertir `Asx` en una lista, para lo cual la debes definir fuera del ciclo, por ejemplo como: `Asx = []` o `Asx = list()`, luego al iterar vas agregando los valores mediante el método propio de la lista [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures). Quedaría algo así:

```
M = [2,5,6,8,7]  
fy = 4200  
h = 30  
b = 20  
d = 0.90*h  

Asx = []
for i in M:  
   Asx.append((i*100000)/(0.81*fy*d))
```

O bien puedes usar comprensión de listas y hacer mas compacto el código de la siguiente forma:

```
Asx = [(i*100000)/(0.81*fy*d) for i in M]
```

Answer (score 0):

Paso todo a **float** para mejorar el resultado.

Las variables que pasas (fuera de la función) son la siguientes:

```
M = [2.0,5.0,6.0,8.0,7.0]
fy = 4200.0
h = 30.0 # sin utilizar
b = 20.0 # sin utilizar
d = 0.90*h

def calcularYDevolverEnLista():
    asx = []
    for i in M:
        asx.append((i*100000.0)/(0.81*fy*d))
    return asx
```

La función **calcularYDevolverEnLista()** se encargara de recorrer la lista de **float** donde guardara insertando en la lista los resultados obtenidos de la formula.
Una vez finalizado el recorrido por **M** devolverla una lista con los resultados obtenidos.

```
print("Lista con valores calculados: ", calcularYDevolverEnLista())
```

El resultado obtenido ser:

```
Lista con valores calculados:  [2.1773684325124654, 5.443421081281164, 6.532105297537396, 8.709473730049861, 7.620789513793629]
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.